# how to use chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ive looked through all(all that I could find) of the chrome.tabs.executeScript documentations, and questions. Nothing seems to work... The code that I've tried is -

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "A de test",

  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "YEET",


  "homepage_url": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbmPRCzP88oaId-4piz5Weg",

  "icons": {
  "128": "icons/Icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icons/Icon-128.png",
  "default_title": "GAME HUB.io TESTING",
  "default_popup": "src/html/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  ]
}
```

Html (src/html/Popup.html) + JS (Popup.js):

```js
document.getElementById("Mr_Button-Click_Extend").addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: 'inject.js'
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="popup.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="Mr_Button-Click_Extend">hello this is a test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Inject.js:

```
document.body.bgColor='red'
```

I have tried it using **all** of the permissions, so I doubt that was it... I also modified my code so that the error logs disappeared... So unless it's an unlisted error that is occurring or its just my browser glitching out (I usually use Opera... But I have chrome and have tested all the methods I've found/modified there too).

Is anyone able to help? I am clueless as to what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: 1. Move popup.js script tag down before the closing tag of body or wrap the code in DOMContentLoaded listener, 2. document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

Comment: wOxxOm - I wish you posted it as an answer, it worked perfectly... I could have given you some credit for that answer... You deserve it... Here... Idea repost your response as an answer and i'll check the box. Thanks dude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1. Move popup.js script tag down before the closing tag of body or wrap the code in DOMContentLoaded listener, 2. document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'` – wOxxOm